# How do I identify the source of incorrect database field name generation in EJB and JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I am working on a project which is pretty much an extension of the Affablebean tutorial.

I have been trying to write data to the database, that is when a customer submits a form to purchase an item for the website.

The key part of the error from the glassfish server log says: `‘Unknown column 'CUSTOMER_CustomerID' in 'field list'’`, which is true, in that the actual column name is `‘CustomerOrderID’`.

I have tried to no avail to find out why the entity framework is generating an incorrect column name and where exactly the problem is originating from, including looking up similar issues on the internet.

Database Code

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryName` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains product category details';    

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `AddressLine1` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `AddressLine2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `CreditCard` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains customer details';


CREATE TABLE `customer_order` (
  `CustomerOrderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ShipperID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `ConfirmationNumber` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains customer order details';


CREATE TABLE `ordered_product` (
  `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` smallint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains ordered product details';


CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SupplierID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProductName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `ProductDescription` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventoryCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains product details';    

CREATE TABLE `shipper` (
  `ShipperID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactTitle` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `AddressLine1` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `AddressLine2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `Website` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains dropshipping partner details';

CREATE TABLE `supplier` (
  `SupplierID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactTitle` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `AddressLine1` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `AddressLine2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `Website` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `StockLevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='maintains product supplier details';
```

Order Manager

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class OrderManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PeripheralsPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;
    @EJB
    private ProductFacade productFacade;
    @EJB
    private CustomerOrderFacade customerOrderFacade;
    @EJB
    private OrderedProductFacade orderedProductFacade;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public int placeOrder(String title, String firstName, String lastName, String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String city, String state, String postCode, String country, String phone, String email, String creditCard, ShoppingCart cart) {        
        try {
            Customer customer = addCustomer(title, firstName, lastName, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postCode, country, phone, email, creditCard);
            CustomerOrder order = addOrder(customer, cart);
            addOrderedItems(order, cart);
            return order.getCustomerOrderID();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.setRollbackOnly();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
    private Customer addCustomer(String title, String firstName, String lastName, String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String city, String state, String postCode, String country, String phone, String email, String creditCard) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setTitle(title);
        customer.setFirstName(firstName);
        customer.setLastName(lastName);
        customer.setAddressLine1(addressLine1);
        customer.setAddressLine2(addressLine2);
        customer.setCity(city);
        customer.setState(state);
        customer.setPostCode(postCode);
        customer.setCountry(country);
        customer.setPhone(phone);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        customer.setCreditCard(creditCard);

        em.persist(customer);
        return customer;
    }

    private CustomerOrder addOrder(Customer customer, ShoppingCart cart) {
        // Set up customer order
        CustomerOrder order = new CustomerOrder();
        order.setCustomer(customer);
        order.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(cart.getTotal()));
        order.setShipperID(null);

        // Create confirmation number
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.nextInt(999999999);
        order.setConfirmationNumber(i);
        out.print(i);

        em.persist(order);
        return order;
    }

    private void addOrderedItems(CustomerOrder order, ShoppingCart cart) {

        em.flush();

        List<ShoppingCartItem> items = cart.getItems();

        // Iterate through the shopping cart and create OrderedProducts
        for (ShoppingCartItem scItem : items) {
            int productId = scItem.getProduct().getProductID();

            // set up primary key object
            OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK = new OrderedProductPK();
            orderedProductPK.setOrderID(order.getCustomerOrderID());
            orderedProductPK.setProductID(productId);

            // create ordered item using PK object
            OrderedProduct orderedItem = new OrderedProduct(orderedProductPK);

            // set quantity
            orderedItem.setQuantity(scItem.getQuantity());

            em.persist(orderedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Server Output Log

```
Finer:   client acquired: 408549163
Finer:   TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finer:   acquire unit of work: 343107320
Finest:   persist() operation called on: entity.Customer[ customerID=null ].
Finest:   persist() operation called on: entity.CustomerOrder[ customerOrderID=null ].
Finer:   begin unit of work flush
Finer:   TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finest:   Execute query InsertObjectQuery(entity.Customer[ customerID=null ])
Finest:   Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
Finest:   reconnecting to external connection pool
Fine:   INSERT INTO customer (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Country, CreditCard, Email, FirstName, LastName, Phone, PostCode, State, Title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [12 parameters bound]
Finest:   Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY" sql="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
Fine:   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
Finest:   assign sequence to the object (15 -> entity.Customer[ customerID=null ])
Finest:   Execute query InsertObjectQuery(entity.CustomerOrder[ customerOrderID=null ])
Fine:   INSERT INTO customer_order (Amount, ConfirmationNumber, CustomerID, ShipperID, CUSTOMER_CustomerID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
Fine:   SELECT 1
Warning:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'CUSTOMER_CustomerID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO customer_order (Amount, ConfirmationNumber, CustomerID, ShipperID, CUSTOMER_CustomerID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(entity.CustomerOrder[ customerOrderID=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:437)
    at session.OrderManager.addOrderedItems(OrderManager.java:131)
    at session.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
    at session.__EJB31_Generated__OrderManager__Intf____Bean__.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
    at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:207)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:413)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'CUSTOMER_CustomerID' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
    ... 100 more

Finer:   TX afterCompletion callback, status=ROLLEDBACK
Finest:   Connection released to connection pool [default].
Finer:   release unit of work
Finer:   client released
```

CustomerOrder

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_order")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "CustomerOrder.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerOrder c")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "CustomerOrder.findByCustomerOrderID", query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerOrder c WHERE c.customerOrderID = :customerOrderID")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "CustomerOrder.findByAmount", query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerOrder c WHERE c.amount = :amount")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "CustomerOrder.findByConfirmationNumber", query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerOrder c WHERE c.confirmationNumber = :confirmationNumber")})
public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CustomerOrderID")
    private Integer customerOrderID;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ConfirmationNumber")
    private int confirmationNumber;
    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerID", referencedColumnName = "CustomerID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Customer customerID;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ShipperID", referencedColumnName = "ShipperID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Shipper shipperID;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerOrder")
    private Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection;
    private Customer customer;

    public CustomerOrder() {
    }

    public CustomerOrder(Integer customerOrderID) {
        this.customerOrderID = customerOrderID;
    }

    public CustomerOrder(Integer customerOrderID, BigDecimal amount, int confirmationNumber) {
        this.customerOrderID = customerOrderID;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerOrderID() {
        return customerOrderID;
    }

    public void setCustomerOrderID(Integer customerOrderID) {
        this.customerOrderID = customerOrderID;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getConfirmationNumber() {
        return confirmationNumber;
    }

    public void setConfirmationNumber(int confirmationNumber) {
        this.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber;
    }

    public Customer getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(Customer customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public Shipper getShipperID() {
        return shipperID;
    }

    public void setShipperID(Shipper shipperID) {
        this.shipperID = shipperID;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<OrderedProduct> getOrderedProductCollection() {
        return orderedProductCollection;
    }

    public void setOrderedProductCollection(Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection) {
        this.orderedProductCollection = orderedProductCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (customerOrderID != null ? customerOrderID.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof CustomerOrder)) {
            return false;
        }
        CustomerOrder other = (CustomerOrder) object;
        if ((this.customerOrderID == null && other.customerOrderID != null) || (this.customerOrderID != null && !this.customerOrderID.equals(other.customerOrderID))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.CustomerOrder[ customerOrderID=" + customerOrderID + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Because in your Entity you have mapped a column incorrectly (or more likely have left it to the persistence provider to deduce the incorrect column name). But you haven't posted the entity classes.

Comment: @AlanHay Thank you very much for replying. The whole entity classes will exceed the character limit, so I have prepped it in Pastebin. Here's the link: https://pastebin.com/raw/3HNRaAhQ

Comment: Just edit the post, OMIT the majority of the database stuff and post the relevant classes for that field/column. i.e just post the relevant info

Comment: @BillyFrost Thank you, Billy. I have now removed the SQL for the DB and added the specific entity class CustomerOrder.java, that I believe is directly concerned with the issue.

Comment: You have a field "private Customer customer;" (no annotations) and also "private Customer customerID;" (with annotations). Are these doing different things? The missing column relates to the former field. Just because there is no annotation doesn't mean it isnt persisted

Comment: Hi @BillyFrost, I think you have spotted it. In short, to address your question, I manually added the field 'private Customer customer' and allied getter and setter methods and I had a feeling it was wrong. The problem I have is that I need the 'Customer' field to be present in the entity class because it is utilized by the OrderManager class to set and get customer at order.setCustomer(customer); and Customer customer = order.getCustomer();. However, as it is not getting automatically generated, I am not quite sure how to go about that. Any ideas or do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "automatically generated". A field is POPULATED when you retrieve an object. If that field is part of a BIDIRECTIONAL relation (with Customer) then you need "mappedBy" on one side of the relation. When setting BIDIRECTIONAL relations you set BOTH sides of the relation

Comment: Hey @BillyFrost, I have just sorted it, thanks to you. By automatic generation, I was referring to the process of generating entity classes from the database, from within the IDE.

Anyway, the values have been written to the database but with a whole different kind of error. I will have a look at it now to see if I can sort it. Meanwhile, I thank you so much for the assistance and I wish you also find help when you need it.

Cheers.